# array[10] vs arrray[n] and segmentation error

Tags: c, arrays

I am a absolute beginner, and I have a confusion that I am unable to point out. Here are two C program

program 1.

[image: for sum of array of big integers]

program 2.

[image: program for same]

Both program are same except in 2 a[n] is used in place of a[10] in 1 ,both are not showing any error in devc++ compiler, but why on hackerrank second program with a[n] showing "segmentation fault" while program 1 is correct

WHAT is "segmentation error" and why it is occurring here in second program and why devc++ doesn't show this error?

Comment: Did you read [ask] ? Read a book of C !

Comment: Please post your code rather than expecting people to click through to an image. Also turn on a higher level of warnings on your compiler.

Comment: in 2nd Ver `a[n]` : The value of `n` has not been determined at this point.

Comment: See [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and talk to the duck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second case, value of n is not initialized. It must have some random value. So you are trying to make a Variable Length Array of a random value. 
Causes of segmentation fault in this case:

- Making a Variable Length Array with uninitialized size

Now imagine when I say random value of n. It may be negative, very large...etc. So making a variable length array with uninitialized size is a bad practice and thus leads to segmentation fault.

---

> What is segmentation fault?

Segmentation fault means that your program is trying to access the area of memory that it is not allowed to. A good article on this topis is [this](http://web.mit.edu/10.001/Web/Tips/tips_on_segmentation.html). Read it carefully and relate your problem to the 4th cause mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

In general segmentation fault occurs when you try to access a memory location, you are not supposed to.

In `program 2` array is declared as `a[n]` where `n` is a variable and is used uninitialized. Variable `n` is used just after declaration, uninitialized.  Here the program is unable to decide how much memory it should allocate to the array. You are initializing `n` after it's first use(`a[n]`)

So when you're trying to access the elements of the array(to find the sum), the program is trying to access memory location it shouldn't. That's where the segmentation fault is occurring..

To fix it initialize `n` with a value or replace `n` in `a[n]` with a value.

Comment: It's useless to initialize the array in the first example, the best is test the return value of `scanf()`. Plus in the second example, the OP clearly want use VLA, and ask to the user how many integer will be enter. Your solution broke this behavior, the best is again to verify `scanf()` return value when the user enter the value of `n` and to move the declaration of the array after that `n` is correctly initialized.

Comment: Yes, It was a mistake.. I've edited the ans

Answer (score -1):

Segmentation fault means that the array is out of bounds. In other words, the program is trying to manipulate or access a data area that was not reserved for the variable. It's the same as Java `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when referring to address outside of a declared array.

In your program 2, `a[n]` does not declare space for the variables that the program tries to store later, therefore there is a segmentation fault.

Comment: "Segmentation fault means that the array is out of bounds.", did I made a out of bound in [this](http://rextester.com/MHZYI13232) example ? Segfaults are caused by a program trying to read or write an illegal memory location.

Comment: Attempts to access an array out of bounds lead to undefined behavior, which may mean a segfault, or may mean the program appears to work correctly, or may mean anything else.

Comment: @Stargateur read or write or execute! (As made clear by your example). Because the process might have read permission on the page but not execute permission.